# TypeScript: Infer class properties from constructor(options) or vice versa

Tags: typescript, class, type-inference

I'm converting some JS to TS, something like this:

```js
class User {
  constructor({ name, age }) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }
  // … + methods
}
```

I was hoping with TypeScript it would be able to infer the properties on `User`, or there would be some way to avoid duplicating the shape of the constructor options object shape and the class shape. However, my attempt of getting TypeScript to infer the class shape from the options did not work:

```js
type UserOptions = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class User {
  constructor(options: UserOptions) {
    this.name = options.name // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User'.
    this.age = options.age // Property 'age' does not exist on type 'User'.
    // or Object.assign(this, options), neither works
  }
}

const user = new User({ name: 'Alice', age: 42 })

console.log(user.name, user.age) // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User'.
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=83#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgeTMAlgewHZygXigG8AoKKbAQwFsIAuKOYRdbAczKkrfooFdqAIyQkAviRIBjADaU4eeEmKdJOJoj6TgmRAApMaLLgaKUhtQEpl5csAAW6OADoqtAlAMY1LmtAD0flAACogGSKBQAOSuEJFQACaYEHjYmMBQEAAejuk4UKCQUaaRTpy2Ds7c0ISeRpU8UAHBoZCIEZFVcYnJFGkZ2Uwe2Png0JHFpTaNgTpQyIIAVhBaTnJw6GzYuvaOADQe5rgW+9gQ6PZKAO46ANZwnOLiUmrpfAiI7qeXsO+6RBS+BiRACC0nQkli+yqDAALAAmKCiCwSVS4TDSCBOaSYNi6N5IHy0fb4xCrHhWJohMJtEBRGJdJIpPpZHJDEaFcbvEpAA

I note that it's able to infer the shapes correctly if I use an object factory function instead of a `class`:

```js
type UserOptions = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

function User(options: UserOptions) {
  return Object.assign({}, options)
}

const user = User({ name: 'Alice', age: 42 })

console.log(user.name, user.age)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgeTMAlgewHZygXigG8AoKKbAQwFsIAuKOYRdbAczKkrfooFdqAIyQkAviRIAzPtgDGGHLASIAYtgAUmNFlwN4SVAtwBKYp0QRgfRNijJBAKwjyAdJThx0bDUVEAaKC0jOGMxCVkcJig+ZQIlJDV1IgoaXgByAEEAG3RZCDSA7l4AFgAmKFFQkgjcTCyIFyzMNnUYpBcqWgC2xDceYyA

Is there some way to tell TypeScript to infer the properties on a `class User` from `UserOptions`, or vice-versa?

I feel like **I shouldn't need to manually duplicate each property definition from `UserOptions` onto `User`**.

Something like the first example in this blog post: https://fettblog.eu/low-maintenance-types-typescript/

Comment: Add the line `interface User extends UserOptions {}` and declaration merging will take effect

Comment: @AluanHaddad Wow, thanks that works but I don't exactly follow as to why. Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgeTMAlgewHZygXigG8AoKKbAQwFsIAuKOYRdbAcwBoypK36KArtQBGSLgF8SJVsCQAzSgGNo8JFAgAPWdgAmeVSjRZcxSSUUAbSnH0JExbopxNEAxcEyIAFJiPOGBqgYzgCUDuTkwAAW6HAAdFS0BFC+wbgJNBDckTHxvNCEqcZ5fNySZk64wFACdsnYEADusHZeRBSZDADkAIIW6MpdHDx8DAAsAExQ4iFSlXCYFhBxFphsXrVIGbTDm4hx+WEA9EdQAAqIvkigUF2JEF1QOpgQeNiY1Zqx1ThQoJC3AxdOJAA

Comment: Glad to help. I'd add an answer but @captain-yossarian already wrote one which applies the same technique and more elegantly, albeit without explanation. The language handbook explains what's going on here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: @AluanHaddad yours is actually a better solution for my particular problem because it keeps the User class type (i.e. data + methods) and the options type (data) separate.

Comment: Ah. Right you are

Answer (score 3):

Here you have other solution:

```js
interface User {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class User {
  constructor(options: User) {
    this.name = options.name
    this.age = options.age 
  }
}

const user = new User({ name: 'Alice', age: 42 })

console.log(user.name, user.age) // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User'.
```